# CSS layout to place a div on center of the screen

Tags: html, css

Again about css layout:

```
#container{
width:979px;
height:590px;
margin-left:auto; //works
margin-right:auto; //works
margin-top:auto; //doesn't work
margin-bottom:auto; //doesn't work
}
```

So, I want #container to place in the center of screen.
I also tried: margin:auto - without result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about something like:

```
#container{
width:979px;
height:590px;
position:absolute;
left:50%;
top:50%;
margin:-295px 0 0 -490px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Or maybe you can use this solution :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="block">
        <p>Hello world, i'm a vertical align div !</p>
    </div>    
</div>

div.bloc { 
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should set it manually by padding if you want to do it with css.
or else if you want it to be dynamic you should write a javascript like following:-

```
var a = window.outerHeight;
var b = $('#id of div').height();
var c = (a-b)/2;
$('#id of div').css("margin-top",c);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `margin-top:50%;` you may have success with that.

Answer (score 1):

The best method is to use `display: table-cell` and `vertical-align: middle` (which doesn't work on IE7-).

Because we don't have your HTML, the best I can do is link you [this article](http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html) which present you all the different method to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the height and width of #container you can do the following:

1. Add a wrapper div around container and set it to position:relative
2. Set #container to be position:absolute, top:50%, left:50%, margin-left:-XXXpx, margin-top:-XXXpx where the XXX values are half of the width and height of your #container.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for *vertical centering*, there is a [blog](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/) about how to do that. Hope helpful.

Comment: Thanks, xiaowl, it will be usefull

Answer (score 0):

If u just want the container to place in the center of the screen. try this

CSS:

```
html, body { margin:0; padding:0; }

#container{
width:979px;
height:590px;
margin:0 auto;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="container">
Data goes here
</div>
```

Hope this helps